# Get/Update "REST Request Properties" value in SOAPUI is coming NULL

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api, getproperty

[image][image][image]I am trying to get the Property value and Set it with different value in SoapUI's  "REST Request Properties" (NOT the custom properties). It just gives me NULL value

Here is what I did:
1. Get test step object
2. get the property value with name of the property   => It is giving me null value.

I know I am getting the correct object as I was able to rename the same Test Step name with following code

```
def restRequest = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Test");
def a = restRequest.getPropertyValue("Method")

log.info(a) // this gives null

restRequest.setName("Test1") // This works
```

Comment: `.getPropertyValue()` reads only the "custom properties". I am not sure if you can get at the metadata. See: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/soapui/index.html?com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStep.html

Comment: Are you able to manually modify the same?

Comment: And which property value are you trying to modify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `step` object, there is another object called *testRequest* from which you can get all those required properties.

For example if you want to get all the properties

```
log.info step.testRequest.metaClass.methods*.name
```

For example if you want to know the *get* methods

```
log.info step.testRequest.metaClass.methods*.name.findAll {it.startsWith('get')}
```

Similarly you can get the methods to *set* the value as well.

For instance, you want to modify `Pretty Print` from `true` to `false`:

```
step.testRequest.setPrettyPrint(false)
log.info step.testRequest.properties['prettyPrint']
```

Similarly, you can find the required property name, find the right method to modify the value as per your needs.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to get all the get and set methods using your code.  I wanted to update the "Resource" property of the "REST Request Properties" for this particular test.

Comment: You could use appropriate method. Are you able to do?

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to get all the get and set methods using your code.  I wanted to update the "Resource" property of the "REST Request Properties" for this particular test. 
testStep.getResource() // gave me current resource value 

Now I want to update the resource name just for this specific test case. 

    testStep.setPath("/testing/123");  

Is there a way to set the resource of the Test Request Properties for a individual test case.  I can update the resource path in different way, but it updates for the entire project which I don't want.

Comment: I have added the screen shot.

Comment: The screen shot of rest request step, mark where to update. Sorry for not being clear earlier.

Comment: I have added the screen shot and circled by red ink for the value where I want to update

Comment: @ktmrocks, thank you. Would you please add why do you want to update the resource value or what is your use case? By the way, resource is read only, so you can set new value. But if you tell the use case, there can be alternatives.

Comment: The Resource contains variables which I need to change dynamically during run time. I do not want to add resources for each method in UI and paramertize there.  My thinking is it will be much easier, cleaner and easy to maintain if I can change that resource from UI dynamically.

I found a way to update the resource by groovy, but it updates the entire project's resource 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495443/how-to-update-resource-value-in-readyapi-soapui-dynamically-by-groovy

Comment: Use case with an example helps.

Comment: Example :  Following is my Resource
  Use case 1 #
    Endpoint/testapi/electronics/category/order/123
Here I want to change value for electronics and 123 dynamically.

Comment: Simple case. Thanks for the example. You Need to use template type parameter in the service definition. And use property expansion in the test cases. And easily have different values.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking to update the resource with groovy so I have more control over it, but your solution is very helpful as well.

Comment: Of course, you can use custom property to update the value from groovy script. However, the key is to use template parameter in any case.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Rao.